# How to natural join the two queries having with clause?

Tags: postgresql

I have written two queries that help in finding the minimum and maximum sales quantities for different products. Now, I need to merge these two queries using natural join to output one single table.

Query 1:

```sql
with max_quant_table as
(with maxquant_table as
(select distinct month,prod as prod, sum(quant) as quant from sales group by month,prod)
 select month as month,prod as MOST_POPULAR_PROD, quant as  MOST_POP_TOTAL_Q
from maxquant_table)
select t2.* from
    (select month, max(MOST_POP_TOTAL_Q) maxQ FROM max_quant_table group by month order by month asc)
    t1 join max_quant_table t2 on t1.month = t2.month and (t2.MOST_POP_TOTAL_Q =maxQ)
```

Query 2:

```sql
with min_quant_table as
(with minquant_table as
(select distinct month,prod as prod, sum(quant) as quant from sales group by month,prod)
 select month as month,prod as LEAST_POPULAR_PROD, quant as  LEAST_POP_TOTAL_Q
from minquant_table)
select t2.* from
    (select month, min(LEAST_POP_TOTAL_Q) minQ FROM min_quant_table group by month order by month asc)
    t1 join min_quant_table t2 on t1.month = t2.month and (t2.LEAST_POP_TOTAL_Q = minQ)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you use `group by month, prod` there is no need to also add a `distinct` to your query.

Answer (score 1):

You are over complicating things. You don't need to join those two query (and should really stay away from a *natural* join), you only need to combine them. `min()` and `max()` can be used inside the same query, there is no need to run two queries to evaluate both.

You also don't need to nest CTE definitions, you can just write one after the other.

So something like this:

```
with quant_table as (
  select month, prod, sum(quant) as sum_q
  from sales 
  group by month, prod
), min_max as (
  select month, max(sum_q) as max_q, min(sum_q) as min_q
  from quant_table 
  group by month 
)
select t1.* 
from quant_table t1
  join min_max t2 
    on t2.month = t1.month 
   and t1.sum_q in (t2.min_q, t2.max_q)
order by month, prod;
```

The condition `and t1.sum_q in (t2.min_q, t2.max_q)` could also be written as `and (t2.max_q = t1.sum_q or t2.min_q = t1.sum_q)`.

---

The above can further be simplified by combining `group by` with [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) and do the calculation of the sum, min and max in a single query:

```
with min_max as (
  select month, prod, 
         sum(quant) as sum_q,
         max(sum(quant)) over (partition by month) as max_q,
         min(sum(quant)) over (partition by month) as min_q
  from sales 
  group by month, prod
)
select month, prod, sum_q
from min_max
where sum_q in (max_q, min_q)
order by month, prod;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I know we can merge `min()` and `max()` in the same query but I want separate tables to be displayed for both the min and max quantities.

Comment: @webMonk: if you want "separate tables" you can't use a join either, as that also produces a single result (=table)