# I have two queries and I want to natural join them so that the table for each quantity is displayed separately

Tags: postgresql

The two queries display max and min quantities along with their products and month, I want to join them to display a single table with each entity(except month) having a seperate column.

Query 1(max):

```sql
with max_quant_table as
   (with maxquant_table as
       (select month,
               prod as prod,
               sum(quant) as quant
        from sales
        group by month,prod)
    select month as month,
           prod as MOST_POPULAR_PROD,
           quant as MOST_POP_TOTAL_Q
    from maxquant_table)
select t2.*
from (select month,
             max(MOST_POP_TOTAL_Q) maxQ
      FROM max_quant_table
      group by month
      order by month asc)t1
   join max_quant_table t2
      on t1.month = t2.month and (t2.MOST_POP_TOTAL_Q = maxQ)
```

Query 2(min):

```sql
with min_quant_table as
   (with minquant_table as
       (select month,
               prod as prod,
               sum(quant) as quant
        from sales
        group by month, prod)
    select month as month,
           prod as LEAST_POPULAR_PROD,
           quant as LEAST_POP_TOTAL_Q
    from minquant_table)
select t2.*
from (select month,
             min(LEAST_POP_TOTAL_Q) minQ
      FROM min_quant_table
      group by month
      order by month asc) t1
   join min_quant_table t2
      on t1.month = t2.month and (t2.LEAST_POP_TOTAL_Q = minQ)
```

Comment: You can `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT /* first query */) AS q1 JOIN (SELECT /* second query */) AS q2 ON /* suitable join condition */`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, can you please provide a working example. It will be a great help.

Comment: How is this different to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/55487837/330315